# Confusion with redirect_uri in OAuth 2.0

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-analytics-api

I have been using Google Analytics for my website which I have [created in weebly](http://cbrokx.weebly.com). I am using the Google APIs to implement the whole thing programmatically.

**The Problem I am facing during the OAuth flow, is that I am getting this error:**

```
Error: redirect_uri_mismatch
The redirect URI in the request:localhost:34190/Callback did not match a registered redirect URI

        Request Details
        scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly
        response_type=code
        access_type=online
        redirect_uri=local_host:34190/Callback
        display=page
        client_id={CLIENT_ID}.apps.googleusercontent.com
```

My google api console config is:

```
Redirect URI: localhost/oauth2callback
JavaScript origins: localhost
```

Why on earth `redirect_uri` is `localhost:34190/Callback` when I set it to: `http://mya.com/oauth2callback`?

**Code which I have written for openauth:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Analytics analytics = initializeAnalytics();
}

private static Analytics initializeAnalytics() throws Exception {
    Credential credential = authorize();
}

private static Credential authorize() throws Exception {
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(
        JSON_FACTORY, Testcode.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secrets.json"));
    FileCredentialStore credentialStore = new FileCredentialStore(
        new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), ".credentials/analytics.json"),
        JSON_FACTORY);
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
        HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets,
        Collections.singleton(AnalyticsScopes.ANALYTICS_READONLY)).setCredentialStore(
            credentialStore).build();
    return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver())
                   .authorize(clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientId());
  }
```

How can I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So your website tells Google to use `localhost:34190/Callback` as redirect URI. But you've said to the Google server, that he only should accept requests when your app specifies `localhost/oauth2callback` as redirect URI.

The easy fix would be to setup Google Console as follows:

```
Redirect URI: http://localhost:34190/Callback
```

Anyway, you are talking about you wanting to redirect to `http://mya.com/oauth2callback`.

In this case you should alter the link the user clicks on your website to specify this

```
[...]&redirect_uri=http://mya.com/oauth2callback[...]
```

and then set this up in Google Console:

```
Redirect URI: http://mya.com/oauth2callback
```

Comment: Thanks Jan!!!!,I had set google api console as localhost:34190 but it's changing everytime, and even mya.com is resolved to localhost in my host file.

Comment: Hey Jan!!!!...information that you have posted I already know, I figured out from other websites.My issue is still unresolved

Comment: Well, with the information in your question it is quite unclear, what issue you are now having. You should either update this question or ask a new one with an exact description of your issue.